# How to make Xcode create xib files as file.xib instead of sourcecode.xib?

Tags: xcode, xib

My xcode start to cracking up and now it always open xib files with XML source editor instead of in interface builder.

I know how to fix this problem for specific file by changing file type at the "Get Info" of the file.

My question is how can i solve the root of the problem and make xcode to make xib files as file.xib by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode preferences under "File Types" make sure xib files are opened using "External Editor (Currently Interface Builder)"

Comment: I did make sure. that is not the problem. xcode know to open file.xib in external editor. the problem is that it dosent know to treat xib file as xib files... (unless you tell him for each file specifically)